# MyBatis dynamically including script

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-sql

I am trying to dynamically include select query based on some input parameters.
The following is what I am trying to achieve.

```html
<sql id="query1">
  SELECT * from 
    table_1
   WHERE a = #{param1}
</sql>

<sql id="query2">
  SELECT * from 
    table_2
   WHERE b = #{param2}
</sql>

<select id = "selectSomethingFromDB">
  <include refid="#{readerIdName}" />
</select>
```

I am planning to pass the sql id name as parameter to the query and trying to dynamically choose the select query based on this param. (Sort of like a factory design implementation).
However #{readerIdName} is not getting replaced with the value I am passing as param.
Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The xml attributes at this level are not evaluated in runtime by mybatis.

You can use a single `<SQL id="...">` query and an `<if test="...">` [dynamic sql](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) in it.